Can't apply default styles using OpenXML
I need to apply default styles to a docx document, I get the styles from the odt file
private void InsertDefaultStyles(DefaultStyle defaultStyle, WordprocessingDocument docxDocument)
{
    var styleDefinitionsPart = docxDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;
    Styles styles = styleDefinitionsPart.Styles;
    if (defaultStyle.Attributes["style:family"] == "paragraph")
    {
        RunPropertiesBaseStyle rPrBaseStyle = new RunPropertiesBaseStyle();
        RunProperties rPr = new RunProperties();

        foreach(var child in defaultStyle.Children)
        {
            if(child is StyleTextProperties)
                rPr.Append(GetFonts(child));
        }
        rPrBaseStyle.Append(rPr);
        styles.Append(rPrBaseStyle);
    }
}
private RunFonts GetFonts(OpenDocumentObject runPropertiesAttr)
{
    RunFonts runFonts = new RunFonts();
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> font in runPropertiesAttr.Attributes)
    {
        switch (font.Key)
        {
            case "style:font-name":
                runFonts.Ascii = font.Value;
                runFonts.HighAnsi = font.Value;

                runFonts.AsciiTheme = null;
                runFonts.HighAnsiTheme = null;
                break;
            case "style:font-name-asian":
                runFonts.EastAsia = font.Value;
                runFonts.EastAsiaTheme = null;
                break;
            case "style:font-name-complex":
                runFonts.ComplexScript = font.Value;
                runFonts.ComplexScriptTheme = null;
                break;
        }
    }
    return runFonts;
}

The styles are obtained correctly and assigned, but in the output xml document the following line is obtained in styles
<w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>
Most likely the problem is in the assignment of the created styles, but I can’t figure out where exactly and what I’m doing wrong
